# Integrate $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(\cos^2{x})^{2-\beta}}{(1+\alpha \cos{x})^{4-\beta}} dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, indefinite-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I would like to find a solution to the following integral.

$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(\cos^2{x})^{2-\beta}}{(1+\alpha \cos{x})^{4-\beta}} dx$

but having some issues.
$0<\alpha<1$ and $0<\beta<2$.
I have tried using contour integration with residues, but I am not getting anything useful. I have similar integrals where people obtain hyper geometric functions, but I am unsure how/why thats done.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? It is recommended on this site to show your efforts.

Comment: What makes you believe that there is a closed-form solution?

Comment: @VVejalla I have tried using contour integration/residues but I am having no luck

Comment: @MarkViola I am not sure if there is a closed form solution, but I have done similar integrals in the past that have closed form solutions

Comment: So, why won't the same methodologies you used befire apply now?

Comment: @MarkViola well the main difference is that I now have the issue of $\beta$, before I used a simplified equation where $\beta=0$, but now I am considering it being a free parameter. This makes it more tricky for me

Comment: The [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Special_cases) (for the 1/denominator) with a [beta integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties) give a hypergeometric representation easily.

Comment: @metamorphy Yes that is true, but I am unsure on how to calculate the entire integral